# Vertical overflow for div inside a td

Tags: html, css

I have a `td` which has bit longer text in it. I have placed the text inside the `div` as follows

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <div class=overflow>This is my text that is a little long.</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now i want to have `overflow-y:visible` for the `div`. But i cannot make it work.

Here is the [EXAMPLE](http://cssdesk.com/DVW2d)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Hide the additional text or expand the `td`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set

```
overflow-y: auto;
```

instead

```
overflow-y:visible
```

to your `css`

**DEMO** `-->` http://cssdesk.com/dKstz

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
height: 40px;
```

use

```
min-height: 40px;
```

in your overflow div!

This way you define a minimum height for the div, but not a maximum one.

DEMO: http://cssdesk.com/dYYJ3

Answer (score -1):

try setting the overflow-y to "auto" in your css